# jQuery UI Accordion Widget: How to have the current page's panel open automatically

Tags: jquery-ui, drupal, jquery-ui-accordion

```
    $.widget( "ui.accordion", {
version: "1.10.2",
options: {
    active: 0,
    animate: {},
    collapsible: true,
    event: "click",
    header: "> li > :first-child,> :not(li):even",
    heightStyle: "content",
    icons: {
        activeHeader: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
        header: "ui-icon-triangle-1-e"
    },

    // callbacks
    activate: null,
    beforeActivate: null
},
```

I'm trying to find if there is a way to have the accordion have the currently active pages' panel open automatically when the page loads. For example, if someone clicked on Section 2 of my accordion, when the link opens can it be set to automatically expand that section's panel in the accordion. I am building this on a Drupal site in conjuction with jQuery UI Theme and jQuery UI Filter. Below is a sample of what my code looks like.

```
[accordion]
<h3>Section 1</h3>
<p><a href="/section1>Section 1 Info</a></p>
<h3>Section 2</h3>
<p><a href="/section2>Section 2 Info</a></p>  
[/accordion]
```

Any help or pointing in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`$("section container>h3:eq(0)").click();` should do the trick

note: replace 'section' with whatever refers to it. it's a dummy there.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge here...Where do I drop that code? "activate"? When you say replace 'section' with what it refers to, what exactly do you mean? Sorry trying to make sense of it all

Comment: Trigger it using a button, to see if the code does exactly what you want, first. Makes your life easier.